# Nosetests start as multiprocess, but only one continues to run

Tags: selenium, nose, multiprocess

I'm running

`nosetests -w tests/ --verbosity=3 --debug --debug-log=tests/logs/debug.log --with-xunit --xunit-file=$CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/nose/junit.xml  --with-flaky --processes=4 --process-timeout=500`

And see all 4 tests start initially (selenium tests, so they launch instances of Chrome) but after most tests finish, all but one chrome instance close.

After a few moments, only a single browser is running, and the tests continue in serial.

What's going on?

Update:

After reading that `--with-xunit` is incompatible with `--processes`, I switched to https://github.com/Ignas/nose_xunitmp and still see the same behavior. New command, below:

`nosetests -w tests/ --verbosity=3 --debug --debug-log=tests/logs/debug.log --xunitmp-file $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/nose/junit.xml  --with-flaky --processes=4 --process-timeout=500 --process-restartworker`

Update 2:

Just want to mention I do see 5 distinct `nosetest` processes in `ps aux`. Looks like one parent and 4 runners? Anyone, I guess they're not crashing, the extra processes just stop processing tests.

Comment: I was facing the same issue, however, I'm using pytest so I'm not sure if an issue is entirely similar> In my case it was the race condition. The driver I was creating was for one for each class(e.g. setup_classs) and running 4 test at load distribution. So at least 2 cases were failing every time. The solution was to create the driver per method e.g. setup_method.

Comment: Can you give a minimal example of some tests to run to reproduce this?